# How can I can validate form fields using sync and async validation rules together on onBlur?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I have form with validation on `onBlur` and `onKeyDown`. My problem is to implement validation of email field. The task is to check this field on frontend side using regex expression and in case of truth I should check it on backend for existing in database using existing API point.
I implement form with function `useForm` that has `initialValues` (object of initial values for the form fields), `callback` (function that invokes after pressing Submit), `validate` (function that validates every form field) as parametres.

```
const useForm = (initialValues, callback, validate) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const performValidation = (name) => {
    const validationErrors = validate({ [name]: values[name] });
    setErrors({...errors, ...validationErrors} );
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if(event.which === ENTER_KEY_CODE || event.which === TAB_KEY_CODE)
      performValidation(event.target.name);
  };

  const handleBlur = ({ target : { name } }) => {
    performValidation(name);
  };
.....
  return {
    values,
    errors,
    handleChange,
    handleKeyDown,
    handleBlur,
  }
}
```

Form React usage:

```
  const {
    values, errors, handleChange, handleKeyDown, handleBlur, handleSubmit,
  } = useForm(initialValuesForRegistration, submitHandler, formValidationFunction);

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
        <Input
          type='text'
          name={formFieldNames.email}
          value={values.email}
          errMessage={errors.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
```

My email validation function:

```
import validateEmail from 'filter-validate-email';

const checkEmail = (value) => {
  if(!validateEmail(value))
    return FORM_EMAIL_INVALID;
  // HERE I need to async check with API point call
};
```

Could you please suggest me some ideas how I can implement this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate email like this:-

```
handleValidation(){
        let fields = this.state.email;
        let errors = {};
        let formIsValid = true;
        if(!fields["email"]){
           formIsValid = false;
           errors["email"] = "Cannot be empty";
        }

        if(typeof fields["email"] !== "undefined"){
           let lastAtPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf('@');
           let lastDotPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf('.');

           if (!(lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && fields["email"].indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (fields["email"].length - lastDotPos) > 2)) {
              formIsValid = false;
              errors["email"] = "Email is not valid";
            }
       }  

       this.setState({errors: errors});
       return formIsValid;
   }
```

Comment: The point is not to write my sync validation function but to handle the situation of double validation with using my existing sync function `checkEmail` and some other function which will call the api point, wait response and set error if it occurs.